# Javascript Regex Only Textbox

Tags: javascript, regex, textbox

I was able to find the solution for this in c# / .net but not for regular web html. If there's already an answer let me know and i'll close question.

How to create a text box that only will allow certain characters (ex. alphanumeric) based on a given regex (ex. [a-zA-Z0-9])? So if a user tries to enter anything else, paste included, it is removed or not allowed.

```
<input type="text" class="alphanumericOnly">
```

Comment: Have you even tried to find a solution that already exists on the web? I am sure they are out there, and I don't really want to be your typist, so go Google it and when you have a question about particulars, come back here - unless you want to pay me to write code for you.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.xploredotnet.com/2007/09/restrict-alphabet-input-in-textbox_20.html

Comment: Right, I could have done that, however using SO for answers also has the possibility to generate discussion, new ideas etc, rather than just a static site. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic function would be this:

```
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
```

This would replace any character that is not described by `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Now you could either put it directly into your element declaration:

```
<input type="text" class="alphanumericOnly" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')">
```

Or (as you used the class hint) you assign this behavior to every `input` element with the class `alphanumericOnly`:

```
var inputElems = document.getElemenstByTagName("input");
for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {
    var elem = inputElems[i];
    if (elem.nodeName == "INPUT" && /(?:^|\s+)alphanumericOnly(?:\s+|$)/.test(elem.className) {
        elem.onkeyup = function() {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
        }
    }
}
```

But it’s probably easier to do that with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or another JavaScript framework:

```
$("input.alphanumericOnly").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Example on how to allow alphanumeric chars and space (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and space, others are eliminated as typed):

```
$('#some_input_field_id').unbind('change keyup paste mouseup').bind('change keyup paste mouseup', function(){if(this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)){this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '');}});
```

2. Example on how to allow only lowercase alpha chars (a-z, others are eliminated as typed):

```
$('#some_input_field_id').unbind('change keyup paste mouseup').bind('change keyup paste mouseup', function(){if(this.value.match(/[^a-z]/g)){this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');}});
```

Etc...

**EDIT:**
As of jQuery version 3.0, `.bind()` and `.unbind()` are deprecated. Instead, if you use jQuery 3.0 (and above), simply use `.on()` and `.off()` event handler attachments, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the input stored as the variable `input`...

```
input.onkeyup(function(e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\W/g, '');
}
```

After every keypress the value of the input will be stripped of any non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a .replace method on the keyup event the input will flicker with the non-alphanumeric characters as they're typed, which appears sloppy and doesn't comply with OCD folks like myself.

A cleaner approach would be to bind to the keypress event and deny the characters before they even arrive at the input, like the following:

```
$('.alphanumericOnly').keypress(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key >= 95 && key <= 122));
});
```

A list of basic keycodes can be found [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) if this particular set doesn't suit your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that at least in my case, with the `paste` and `drop` events, replacing the text wasn't working because at that point the `value` property of the input was still the previous one. So I did this:

With pure javascript:

```js
function filterInputs() {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    that.value = that.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
  }, 0);
}

var input = document.getElementById('theInput');

input.addEventListener('keyup', filterInputs);
input.addEventListener('paste', filterInputs);
input.addEventListener('drop', filterInputs);
input.addEventListener('change', filterInputs);
```

```html
Try writing non-alphanumeric characters: <input type="text" id="theInput">
<br>You can use this input to write anything and copy-paste/drag & drop it into the other one: <input type="text">
```

With jQuery:

```js
function filterInputs() {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    that.value = that.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
  }, 0);
}

$('#theInput').on('keyup paste drop change', filterInputs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Try writing non-alphanumeric characters: <input type="text" id="theInput">
<br>You can use this input to write anything and copy-paste/drag & drop it into the other one: <input type="text">
```